# SharePoint online view where Checked Out To is blank

Tags: sharepoint-views

I created a view in a SharePoint Online library where the Checked Out To field it Not Equal to "blank" meaning I didn't put anything into the field.  This does not give me any results.
How can I see all documents in a library that are currently checked out?

Comment: Are you sure that the setting for the files to be checked-out is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your view show where the **Checked Out To** field is **Not Null**. Unfortunately, although totally supported, this isn't an option in the UI. I wrote a post a while back where I did this same filter on the **Checked Out To** field:

https://thechriskent.com/2013/02/14/unpublished-view/

The gist is that you'll need to edit the CAML query of the view directly using SharePoint Designer. Here's how that CAML might look for just that field:

```
<Where>
  <IsNotNull>
    <FieldRef Name="CheckoutUser"/>
  </IsNotNull>
</Where>
```

Here's some documentation that may help as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms465807.aspx

Comment: It does not show sub-folders in cases when files are checked-out within them